# Why is v-model not showing up? Need to show value when in edit mode on form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, templates, vue.js

Hey I'm a front end developer looking to integrate some back end data that is using vue JS, which I am very new to.

I have a form, and when the user clicks "edit" I am showing that same form but I want the values to be populated.

Here is the relevant JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    new Vue({
        el: 'body',

        data: { 

            editMode: false,


            challenge: null,

            challenges: <%= raw @campaign.challenges.to_json(include: [:challenge_tags, :challenge_filters], methods: [:has_link, :encoded_link, :is_active, :contact_count, :total_clicks, :default_image, :completions, :total_targeted, :total_contacts]) %>,
        },

        methods: {

           edit: function(challenge) {
            this.editMode = true;
            this.challenge = challenge; **
           }
        }
    })    
});
```

** this was a suggestion but it didn't seem to work.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="challenge name" v-model="challlenge.name">
```

This, for example, is working correctly:

```
<span v-if="editMode">Edit</span>
```

It is ideal to make it work with v-model.

Any advice helpful!

Edit: When I add v-if="challenge.name" the field does not show up, which is telling me that maybe the data is not being accessed?

Comment: thanks @bert for reformatting, you beat me to it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do it like this `v-if="challenges && challenges.name"` the field will be shown when there is data available in challenges.name

Comment: this seems to just make the input field only appear if that data is available. which is helpfulin the sense that i see that that data is not available...